# Linearization of differential equations system

Tags: dynamical-systems

After linearizing a system of differential equations (non-linear, on two variables), the Jacobian matrix at the equilibrium $(0,1)$ is as follows:

$$ J_{(0,1)}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you can see, the eigenvalues are $0$ and $2$. I know that this linear system has a line of equilibriums, but what does this say about the original (non-linear) system? The Hartman-Grobman theorem (or linearization theorem) is inconclusive in this case, since it does not consider the case where the determinant of the Jacobian is $0$, but there must be something we can say about the system.

Edit: decided to add the non-linear system below.

$$x'=x(x-2)(y-1), y'=y(y^2-x^2+x-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

The equilibrium $(0,1)$ is unstable, since the line $x=0$ is invariant, and on this line the system reduces to single ODE $\dot y=y(y^2-1) = y(y+1)(y-1)$, which has an unstable equilibrium at $y=1$. (That is, perturbations of the equilibrium $(0,1)$ in the $y$ direction will cause the system to move away from $(0,1)$ along the $y$ axis.)

Comment: That seems very plausible, thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, this is not only "very plausible" but a proof in the full sense of the term.